# Non-Linear PDE's: Steady State solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Non-Linear PDE's: Reaction-Diffusion Equation: Fisher's Equation w/ harvesting?

Ok so I am dealing with a spatially dependent logistic equation:

$u_t = u_{xx} + u(1-u) - h,$ 
on 0 ≤ x ≤ L w/ homogenous Dirichlet at x = 0 & homogenous Neumann at x = L boundary conditions 
$u(0,t) = 0, u_x(L,t) = 0$

Now I converted this pde (partial differential equation) to system of 2 ode (ordinary differential equation)

so $u_x = v$ & $v_x = -u(1 - u) - h$

The question I am having trouble w/ asks.

Find steady state solution in the phase plane for small h > 0. 
What is the range for h > 0 that supports a steady state solution

Now I am solving for the steady state solutions

So setting both $u_x$  &  $v_x$ to zero

$u_x = v = 0. $

$v_x = u = -u(1 - u) - h = 0,$ solve for u

i realized that this is a quadratic equation, so i expanded it to $u^{2} - u - h = 0$

$u = \frac{-b ± \sqrt{b^{2}-4*a*c}}{2}$

$u = \frac{1 ± \sqrt{1+4*h}}{2}$

I get the steady state solutions as $u = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+4*h}}{2}$ , $v = 0$ or $u = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+4*h}}{2}$ , $v = 0$

exact possible range of h so that steady state solution becomes real values (for both of the steady states) is

range of h is (0, ∞]

However, when I crossed-check with the instructor she said my u is incorrect.

Is there somewhere I went wrong in my calculations because i reworked the problem but keep getting the same answer again.

Any help appreciated

Comment: First, notice that $v_x = - u(1-u) {\color{red}+} h$.  A more important thing is that, among constant (in $x$) functions, only the zero function satisfies the Dirichlet boundary condition at $x = 0$.

Comment: How comes it is +h and not -h?

Comment: Also, then if we are adding h, then when I solve for it there will be no h > 0 that will result in real values. So am I missing a step when solving for u?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. My solution is producing correct results. Thanks for help